# How to unbind or clear MvvmCross fluent bindings

Tags: ios, data-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross, fluent

I am using MVVMCross fluent bindings in a Xamarin iOS project I am using a MvxFluentDescriptionSet to set up my bindings.

Is there anyway to unbind for clear these bindings? The API only allows me to Apply the bindings. Am I missing something or is it impossible.

The reason I want to do this is that I have a custom control which I need to dispose. But I get  binding exception at this point because it is trying to access the control I have just disposed.

Is there anyway round this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're on iOS, you need to use [`BindingContext.ClearAllBindings()`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/f7fcf18d960f578b851837f2aaaeb4d0e3b72364/MvvmCross/Core/Binding/BindingContext/IMvxBindingContext.cs#L29) (or the extension method [`this.ClearAllBindings()`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/f7fcf18d960f578b851837f2aaaeb4d0e3b72364/MvvmCross/Core/Binding/BindingContext/MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.Clear.cs#L19) which, under the hood, calls the first method) in order to clear the bindings for some context.

Comment: Yes. The thing that confused me was that I was just trying to use ClearAllBindings(), but visual studio showed no intellisense. I type in this.ClearBindings intellisense shows it.